# SwiftUI closure update @State inside init

Tags: swiftui

When I create a view I wish to login the user and when the login is complete, the view will change.

As I am quite new to SwiftUI it seems the way I am trying to this is not working. (I do know it has something to do with SwiftUI structs)

1. I have a state variable to know if the progressView should animate

```
@State private var isLoading: Bool = true
```

2. I have an escaping closure to login user

```
init() {
    userService.login { (didError, msg) in
    }
}
```

3. Progress view(haven't tested it out yet)

```
ProgressView().disabled(isLoading).frame(alignment: .center)
```

When I try to do:

```
userService.login { (didError, msg) in
    isLoading.toggle() or self.isLoading.toggle()
}
```

Xcode return: Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter.

Does anyone know how I can make something like this work?

Comment: This type of functionality is not allowed in a struct. Create a view model as a class. Then put this code in the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `init` call it in `.onAppear` somewhere inside `body`, like

```
var body: some View {
   VStack {
      // .. some content
   }
   .onAppear {
      userService.login { (didError, msg) in
         self.isLoading.toggle()
      }
   }
}
```